# How to compare dynamic objects

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have a `LambdaExpression` that pulls all properties from a `DynamicObject` and calls a method with it's value that is compiled into a `delegate`. By `DynamicObject` I mean anything that implements `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`, not just `ExpandoObject`.

I need a way to tell of the `dynamic` object type is the same as another, so I can cache the `delegate`.

The types all seem to be the same, as they all have the same properties on them. The `Expression` code that is generated to pull the property values is created by using `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder.GetMember`. If the `dynamic` type is an `ExpandoObject`, the generated code will check if the expando types are the same by calling this `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeOps.ExpandoCheckVersion`. To me, the types seem the same because it has the same properties. I don't know what it's seeing different on some of the objects where that version check returns `false`.

So I need a way to compare `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` object types, that will pass the `RuntimeOps.ExpandoCheckVersion` check when the type is `ExpandoObject`.

Maybe there is a better way to create an expression to pull a property from a `dynamic` object. This is what I'm doing in case someone can come up with something better.

```
var type = provider.GetType();
var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter( typeof( object ), "record" );

var metaObject = provider.GetMetaObject( parameterExpression );
var propertyNames = metaObject.GetDynamicMemberNames();

var delegates = new List<Delegate>();
foreach( var propertyName in propertyNames )
{
    var getMemberBinder = (GetMemberBinder)Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder.GetMember( 0, propertyName, type, new[] { CSharpArgumentInfo.Create( 0, null ) } );
    var getMemberMetaObject = metaObject.BindGetMember( getMemberBinder );
    var fieldExpression = getMemberMetaObject.Expression;
    fieldExpression = Expression.Call( Expression.Constant( this ), "WriteField", new[] { typeof( object ) }, fieldExpression );
    fieldExpression = Expression.Block( fieldExpression, Expression.Label( CallSiteBinder.UpdateLabel ) );
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda( fieldExpression, parameterExpression );
    delegates.Add( lambda.Compile() );
}

var delegate = delegates.Aggregate<Delegate, Delegate>( null, Delegate.Combine );
```

The `Expression` code that is generated for a single property on an `ExpandoObject` looks like this.

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Action`1[System.Object]>(System.Object $record) {
    .Block() {
        .Call .Constant<CsvHelper.CsvWriter>(CsvHelper.CsvWriter).WriteField(.If (
                .Call System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeOps.ExpandoCheckVersion(
                    (System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject)$record,
                    .Constant<System.Object>(System.Dynamic.ExpandoClass))
            ) {
                .Block(System.Object $value) {
                    .If (
                        .Call System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeOps.ExpandoTryGetValue(
                            (System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject)$record,
                            .Constant<System.Object>(System.Dynamic.ExpandoClass),
                            0,
                            "Id",
                            False,
                            $value)
                    ) {
                        $value
                    } .Else {
                        .Throw .New Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException("'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'Id'")
                    }
                }
            } .Else {
                .Goto CallSiteBinder.UpdateLabel { }
            });
        .Label
        .LabelTarget CallSiteBinder.UpdateLabel:
    }
}
```

**Update**

After some digging, I'm finding there is an issue with the `ExpandoObject`. `ExpandoObject` has an internal property called `Class` which is of type `ExpandoClass`. `ExpandoClass` claims this `Expando objects which share the same members will share the same class.` I'm finding this to not be true. I'm getting `ExpandoClass` objects on the `ExpandoObject` that have the same list of properties, but are not equal. They return a different hashcode. I can't seem to figure out what is causing this to happen. Because of this, I will probably have to treat `ExpandoObject`s differently.

I still need to know if there is an easy way, or at least a not very expensive way to tell if an `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` is equal to another. Maybe I can just check `GetDynamicMemberNames` and hash the names or something.

Comment: What about manually checking that both objects has the same set of properties (so, both property names and types match).

Comment: They do match. Same type of `ExpandoObject`, and same list of properties.

Comment: I mean, why use ExpandoCheckVersion at all?

Comment: I'm not. Calling `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder.GetMember` generates an `Expression` that calls it.

Comment: I added some code examples.

Comment: Maybe you can provide more info. As I understand, you cache your list of delegates, so that if another dynamic object with the same properties passed to you - you can reuse your delegates and not compile them again. I ran your code, cached those delegates and then passed another ExpandoObject to those delegates (not the same which was used to compile them), and all went without errors.

Comment: I added another line. `var delegate = delegates.Aggregate<Delegate, Delegate>( null, Delegate.Combine )` That is the delegate for the type that gets cached.

Comment: I'll see if I can come up with a small failing example that I can post here. Currently, this is pulling in data from a file, converting that data to dynamic objects (ExpandoObject in this case), then converts them back, which is where this code is ran.

Comment: Yes need some test example, because as is (even with combined delegate) it works fine when passing different ExpandoObjects (with the same set of properties of course).

Comment: I'm not able to create an example that fails either. The data I have is proprietary, so I'm not able to share that unfortunately. My guess based on everything here is that the properties are different some how. If I spit out a list of the properties, they're all the same, but that `ExpandoCheckVersion` fails, which is why I'm looking for another way to verify if the `ExpandoObject` types are the same. From what I can tell, I can't call `ExpandoCheckVersion` because it's internal, or I would at least be using that to try and debug this.

Comment: Maybe some types are different? Like short vs int, or float vs double. Or even int? vs int, something like that.

Comment: They are all strings.

Comment: ExpandoCheckVersion is not internal by the way, it's public so you can call it (though it's marked as Obsolete).

Comment: I had to use reflection to call it, but it worked. I'm able to get that returning false on the same record where I thought they were different. I basically have to do this `ExpandoCheckVersion( currentExpando, previousExpando.Class )`. Class is internal, so again more reflection. ExpandoClass is supposed to keep track of types being equal. The expando objects themselves have identical keys, but the ExpandoClasses aren't equal. Trying to figure out how that is possible now.